# log shipping error

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

i have several databases log shipped from primary to secondary servers.  most work fine however i have one that fails after 1 or 2 cycles.  log shipping is on a 15 min schedule. i have been trying to find the cause of the failure with little luck.  as i say not all log shipped databases fail from primary to secondary. i have compared settings and try monitoring.  i see once it fails it gets stuck and needs resetup to get it back but it will quickly fail.

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4532098) - 11.0.7493.4 (X64) Dec 24 2019 19:33:24 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor) – Ed Hall Jan 25 at 14:23

here is the latest failure message:

```
021-01-29 09:21:04.48   *** Error: Could not apply log backup file '\\Secondary\SQLLogShip\DBname_20210129141502.trn' to secondary database 'DBname'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.48  *** Error: An error occurred while processing the log for database 'DBname'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.
An error occurred during recovery, preventing the database 'DBname' (19:0) from restarting. Diagnose the recovery errors and fix them, or restore from a known good backup. If errors are not corrected or expected, contact Technical Support.
RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.
Processed 0 pages for database 'DBname', file 'DBname' on file 1.
Processed 1 pages for database 'DBname', file 'DBname_log' on file 1.(.Net SqlClient Data Provider) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.48  *** Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.52  *** Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  Skipping log backup file '\\Secondary\SQLLogShip\DBname_20210129141502.trn' for secondary database 'DBname' because the file could not be verified.
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: An error occurred restoring the database access mode.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: An error occurred restoring the database access mode.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  Deleting old log backup files. Primary Database: 'DBname'
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  Deleting log backup file. File: '\\Secondary\SQLLogShip\DBname_20210128141501.trn', Last Write Time (UTC): '1/28/2021 2:15:02 PM'
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-01-29 09:21:04.54  *** Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data) ***
```

What am i missing to get this log shipping to work.

how do i find details on the error so i can eliminate it.

Comment: >>>Diagnose the recovery errors and fix them<<< Check the errorlog for errors. It may be corrupted log file on your secondary

Comment: >>>nothing in the error log i looked before i posted<<< If I were you I restored this db with recovery and ran checkdb on it, your log file seems to be corrupted

Comment: For each of the backups from this database (Full and Transaction Log) try running ```RESTORE VERIFYONLY``` to eliminate whether the backups themselves are becoming corrupted.

On the Primary copy of the database, ensure that you have successfully run ```DBCC CHECKDB```.

Report back with the outcomes of these.

Answer (score 0):

Is your log shipping secondary configured in standby mode?

If yes be sure to check this flag:
[image]

Eventually take a look at the backup history to find intruders in the log chains:

```
DECLARE @db_name VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @db_name = 'DBname'
-- query
SELECT TOP (30) s.database_name
,m.physical_device_name
,CAST(CAST(s.backup_size / 1000000 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(14)) + ' ' + 'MB' AS     bkSize
,CAST(DATEDIFF(second, s.backup_start_date, s.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + 'Seconds' TimeTaken
,s.backup_start_date
,CAST(s.first_lsn AS VARCHAR(50)) AS first_lsn
,CAST(s.last_lsn AS VARCHAR(50)) AS last_lsn
,CASE s.[type] WHEN 'D'
THEN 'Full'
WHEN 'I'
THEN 'Differential'
WHEN 'L'
THEN 'Transaction Log'
END AS BackupType
,s.server_name
,s.recovery_model
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset s
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m ON s.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
WHERE s.database_name = @db_name
ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC
,backup_finish_date
```

Comment: yes it is goin g into standby read only mode and yes it is checked.  this error occurs right after 2021-01-29 10:21:01.64 Disconnecting users. Secondary DB: 'Dbname'

Comment: nothing in the error log i looked before i posted.

Comment: Are you taking others LOG backup or the log shipping log backup is the only one?

Comment: there is anoter log backup job but this database is excluded.  i even disabled it as a test nd the error was the same

Comment: please test it with the query above, look up at the physical device name to find different targets

Comment: run on primary or secondary

Comment: primary, where backups are taken

Comment: physical_device_name bkSize TimeTaken backup_start_date first_lsn last_lsn BackupType recovery_model
\\Secondary\SQLLogShip\DBname_20210129140000.trn 0 MB 0 Seconds 1/29/2021 98910000001813400000 98910000001825000000 Transaction Log FULL
\\Primary\Logshipping\DBname\DBname.bak 5735 MB 37 Seconds 1/29/2021 98910000001814800000 98910000001824200000 Full FULL
\\secondary\SQLLogShip\DBname_20210128220001.trn 0 MB 0 Seconds 1/28/2021 98843000001627300000 98843000001632500000 Transaction Log FULL

Comment: on primary all log backups going to same place